# Pairing Lat/Long coordinates to x/y coordinates of image in picture box

Tags: vb.net, image, mapping

**The core questions is: How do I interpolate 4 lat/long values paired to x/y coordinates across the entire image**

For the ease of this question let's assume my image will be static.

I have a picture box with an image that has a

- height of 638 pixels
- width of 1024 pixels.

I have a geocoded tab file for this image that has lat/long pairs for x/y pairs along with the projection.

```
(-86.672304,36.132795) (443,30) Label "Pt 1",
(-86.672192,36.133032) (475,56) Label "Pt 2",
(-86.669807,36.13234) (286,290) Label "Pt 3",
(-86.670073,36.132034) (246,248) Label "Pt 4"
CoordSys Earth Projection 1, 104
Units "degree"
```

I'm trying to figure out how I take these 4 points and extend my lat/long to x/y conversion for each pixel.

I believe all I need to do now is apply some sort of scale.  I can figure the delta between each of the points on a 2 dimensional plane but I'm not sure how to coordinate that.

I am using the following function to determine distance between points

```
Private Function distanceBetweenPoints(ByRef pt1x As Double, ByRef pt1y As Double, ByRef pt2x As Double, ByRef pt2y As Double)
    Dim p1x As Double = pt1x
    Dim p1y As Double = pt1y
    Dim p2x As Double = pt2x
    Dim p2y As Double = pt2y
    Dim pointDelta As Double
    Dim xDiff As Double = (p2x - p1x) ^ 2
    Dim yDiff As Double = (p2y - p1y) ^ 2

    pointDelta = Math.Sqrt(xDiff + yDiff)
    Return pointDelta

End Function
```

and using it the following way

```
delta1 = distanceBetweenPoints(pt1x, pt1y, pt2x, pt2y)
```

So this will give me the distance in a straight line based on my lat and long.

If I do the same for my x/y pixel I should be able to get the pixel distance then I should be able to divide lat/long delta by pixel delta to get the width of each pixel.

Comment: If each coord is a valid Lat/Long and you can convert it to image px location, doesnt each result stand on its own?  It would not seem to be a point to point issue but lat/long to point. ...Or is that maybe the real question?

Comment: Well, I have a list of points that I would like to plot to the image.  If I have a building floorplan image and i've collected 1 air sample every .2 meters so I have coordinate pairs with data that I want to plot on top of the image I would need to know the lat/long value at each x/y pixel value wouldn't I?

Comment: Yes,  Given the title and the bold portion of the post, I thought the starting point was a list of Lat/Long